# Mariadb password in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql, aws, wordpress, mariadb

I setup a password for Mariadb when I ran `sudo mysql_secure_installation` but when I try to run mariadb with `mysql -u root -p` I get the following error.

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS's Lightsail VPS. I am using Mariadb version `10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT user,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| user          | plugin      | host      |
+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| root          | unix_socket | localhost |
| wordpressuser |             | localhost |
+---------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Secondly, I am confused about what is the proper way to setup and use Mariadb.

1. Should I setup a password when it asks for me during `mysql_secure_installation`?
2. Should mysql be accessed using `sudo mysql` or `mysql -u root -p`?

I can setup a password as instructed on [JournalDev](https://www.journaldev.com/25670/install-wordpress-nginx-ubuntu#step-2-install-mariadb) but I was wondering what is the right way to do it.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]> update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("Passw0rd!") WHERE USER='root';
```

Comment: Maybe [that](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/13554233) helps if you can google translate from Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read here which should answer all your questions:
[Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/)

Basically, by default the root mysql account is secured using the `unix_socket` plugin so that only the root Ubuntu user can logon to the root database user. So `sudo mysql -u root mysql` should work but `mysql -u root mysql` as a non-root user will not.

It's possible to change this behaviour and use password authentication if you really need to (see linked article) but you **may** be making your database less secure. It really depends on your use-case and needs.

Comment: I glanced through that page but it was hard to understand a lot of terminology at first glance. I was thrown off by the fact the mysql_secure_installation suggests setting a password during the setup whereas Mariadb had unix_socket which disallows login to root from a local client.

Shortly after I posted I came across [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/ottokekalainen/less-passwords-more-security-unix-socket-authentication-and-other-mariadb-hardening-tips) which clears the doubt. AKA I should ignore setting password and use sudo to access mysql.